# Using model uncertainties in optimisation

Tags: optimization, uncertainty

I have a cost function which I am minimizing which has no particular meaning beyond a smaller value indicating a more favorable set of parameters. Since I posted the original question it has occurred to me that I could probably write the cost function as a combination of probabilities- although I was hoping to keep the question as general as possible with respect to the cost function.

The aim of the optimization is to find the 'best' design of an optical detector. There are various free parameters in the minimization such as detector element arrangement, no pixels per detector etc. The minimization of the cost function (and fitting of experimental data) was carried out using a BFGS minimizer.

During the evaluation of the cost function for a given set of parameters a number of models are evaluated to simulate the detector which use parameter values determined from experiment. For example, one experiment measured the probability of a detector pixel firing not in the presence of light (so-called dark noise). Such events are almost perfectly Poisson distributed at constant temperature so I was searching for the decay constant.

These were fitted to the model using the MLE method (Gaussian, Poisson and binomial - depending on the situation). As such I have the full correlated uncertainties for the fitted parameters (I assume the models are independent). Is there anyway that I can build this uncertainty into my cost function? Is this part of what might be called robust optimization?

Comment: Can you give more details regarding the cost function and how you're minimizing it? Also, how do you evaluate the models? How are parameter values determined from experiment? What data are you collecting from the experiments? Please revise question to include more information.

Comment: I may be off, but it sounds like you would like to say during the optimization, that some values of the parameters are more likely than the others.  If my assumption is correct then instead of ML estimator you should do MAP estimation. ML basically says that the parameters is a constant (unknown) value which you search for.  MAP looks at the parameters as random variables, so it will allow you to impose prior distributions onto the parameter values.  Again, sorry if I am off...